# siunitx inconsistent when using parse-numbers=false

Tags: siunitx

In the MWE below I was expecting that even with the option `parse-numbers=false`. I would have the `f` written in math mode, not as regular text.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\begin{document}

\noindent
using siunitx (normal): $\SI[parse-numbers=false]{f \pm \Delta}{\Hz}$\\
using siunitx (hacked): $\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\text{$f$} \pm \Delta}{\Hz}$\\
math: $f$\\
roman: f

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use `\si{}` instead? `\SI{}{}` is for typesetting numbers with units, not units alone.

Comment: @erik - Maybe the OP is keen on getting the correct space between `\Delta` and `Hz` -- which won't be obtained if one writes `$f\pm\Delta\si{\Hz}$`.

Comment: The main idea was in fact to use the correct spacing

Comment: In that case I think `$f \pm \Delta\,\si{\Hz}$` would do the trick. I also like that `\SI{}{}` handles the spacing automatically, but the function is designed to accept numbers in the first argument, which is why `parse-numbers=false` isn't useful if you don't have numbers.

Comment: It is written in math mode, but in `\mathrm` as that's the most sensible font choice on average (it's a number so any non-digit content should be upright not italic).

Comment: @JosephWright If you don't have math mode (i.e. just `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{f \pm \Delta}{\Hz}`) the `f` is printed in (math?) italic, is that then expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preferred to use `\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\text{$f \pm \Delta$}}{\Hz}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{f \pm \Delta}{\Hz}$\\
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\text{$f \pm \Delta$}}{\Hz}\\ % <- my solution
math: $f$\\
text: f
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

While the `siunitx` package greatly simplifies typesetting and spacing of numbers, angles, units, etc., this question demonstrates how `\SI{}{}` expects numbers in the first argument (and the reason for having a separate function `\si{}`). In this case, I think using the units-only command `\si{}` and explicitly defining the spacing with `\,` is the better approach. The results should be identical.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}
\begin{document}
\noindent
$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{f \pm \Delta}{\Hz}$\\
$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{\text{$f$} \pm \Delta}{\Hz}$\\
$f \pm \Delta\,\si{\Hz}$\\
math: $f$\\
roman: f
\end{document}
```

[image]